# Android programming auto sms

Tags: android, sms

I have an application which sends an auto SMS when I receive an SMS, or missed cal etc.   So, if the  same application is there in the opposite person's phone, then the the process of sending SMS continues, which should not happen.  How to avoid this?

In fact, how to detect an SMS, which is sent by user or auto replied?

Please try to explain  programmatically as clearly as possible..

Comment: please try to explain you question more understandable, and programatically .. Add some code parts which you try to do and etc.

Comment: well the question is pretty clear.. meher you can add a tag in the body of your sms.. which would tell the receiving side application that it is auto generated. Tag should also be human readable i.e if receiver dont have the application, it doesn't give the idea to the user that it is a tag... one of the approach...

Answer (score 1):

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null,"sam", null, null);
```